# How can I know the journal still covered by Scopus (include 2018 year)

Tags: scopus

How can I know the journal still covered by Scopus, for example when I check it on Scopus site " Scopus coverage years: from 2008 to 2018 " what its mean?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can't you just search Scopus for the journal? As for "Scopus coverage years: from 2008 to 2018", where is it in Scopus's website? Can you link?

Comment: https://www.scopus.com/sourceid/11900154360

Answer (score 2):

Scopus offers a list of discontinued sources (under "[Content Coverage](https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus/how-scopus-works/content?dgcid=RN_AGCM_Sourced_300005030)", at the very bottom).

[image: Screenshot of Scopus' link to discontinued sources]